# How to create Temporary table with Dynamic query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to create Temporary table dynamically in SQL Server 2005 like below.

```
Create Table ##EmpMonthlyTimeReport
(
    EmpID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    EmpName VARCHAR(100),
    TaskId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [07 Nov] NVARCHAR(10),
    [08 Nov] NVARCHAR(10),
    [09 Nov] NVARCHAR(10)
)
```

In the above **##EmpMonthlyTimeReport** table, columns [07 Nov], [08 Nov], [09 Nov] are **NOT** static. They are creating dynamically through another function.

Hence, I am dynamically constructing the above table in one variable called **@EmpMonthlyTimeReport** and I'm executing the constructed sql string like below:

```
EXEC(@EmpMonthlyTimeReport)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SVS_WorkOnWeekends, Line 157
The name 'INSERT INTO ##EmpMonthlyTimeReport(EmpID, EmpName, TaskId)
SELECT EmpId, EmpName, TaskId FROM TableData 
SELECT * FROM ##EmpMonthlyTimeReport
DROP TABLE ##EmpMonthlyTimeReport' is not a valid identifier.
```

Comment: you are not dropping the right table

Comment: Hi donebizkit, Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am dropping right table only. But, here it was happened just because of copy paste problem.

Comment: Remove the space between the cloumn names of _[07 Nov]_, _[08 Nov]_, _[09 Nov]_

Comment: Hi Manikandan, It does not matter as long as column names are inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very silly work around.

I have changed the @EmpMonthlyTimeReport variable declaration from VARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(MAX)

That's it. Everything is working as expected.